# Item of JSON displays "null" when sending it from Raspberry to Arduino

Tags: raspberry-pi, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

I'm working on a project where I need to send a JSON from a Raspberry to an Arduino as JSON, but when I try to read the item I send, it displays "null"

```
void printText(String string, int row, int col = 0){
  lcd.setCursor(col, row);
  lcd.print(string);
}

void readJSON()
{
  jsonInput = Serial.readString();
  StaticJsonDocument<200> json;
  deserializeJson(json, jsonInput);
  if (json["cmd"] == "RFID")
  {
    if(json["valid"]){
      blinkGreenLED();
      auto mm = json["timeFrame"]["mins"];
      auto ss = json["timeFrame"]["secs"];
      //Serial.println(mm);
      printText("Access granted!", 0);
      printText("Checkpoint " + json["checkpoint"].as<String>(), 1);
      printText("Time left: " + mm.as<String>() + ":" + ss.as<String>(), 2);
      }
  
    else {
      blinkRedLED();
      printText("Access denied!", 0);
    }
  }
}
```

Weirdly, the "json["checkpoint"]" is shown as expected and displays "1", but the mm and ss are displayed as "null".
Does anyone know what causes this? Thank you in advance!
This is my JSON:

```
{
    "cmd": "RFID",
    "valid": true,
    "checkpoint": 1,
    "timeFrame": {
        "mins": 5,
        "secs": 0
    }
}
```

I tried all sorts of converting it to String by saving it as integer and then converting it, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Arduinios are _very_ resource-constrained - so sending JSON over-the-wire just seems... excessive and wasteful. Is htere a reason you're not using a binary serialization format? What advantages does _textual_ JSON give you that a custom wire format, or even BSON, don't?

Comment: Use `json["timeFrame"]["mins"].as<String>()` instead of assigning the jsonObject to an `auto` (which is an `int`, which doesn't have a member method of `.as<String>()`). I'm surprise that you don't get an compiler error on that.

Comment: I didn't know there was another way to send the JSON. I was thought it that way. Good to know that there are more efficient ways. Thank you. 
For the JSON this solved the issue. Thank you. Apparently Arduino ide uses an outdated compiler so this could be the reason.